# Next/Prev Button "stopper". Set min and max. value

Tags: javascript

this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content span").html(i)/55;
    var i = 1;
    $("#n_next").click(function(){
        i++;
        $("#content span").html(i)/55;
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    });

     $("#n_prev").click(function(){
        i--;
        $("#content span").html(i)/55;
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    });
});

<div><img id="changer1" alt="before" src="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/1/before.jpg" width="540" height="360" /> <img id="changer2" alt="after" src="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/1/after.jpg" width="540" height="360" />
<div style="float:right" id="content"><span>1</span>/55</div>

<img src="img/prev.png" id="n_prev"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/trnn.png"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/next.png" id="n_next"/>
```

So basically the folder just change on click. When next button +1 and prev button -1. It works perfect. There is just one little problem. My counter can go to -numbers and over 55... Can someone help me to make some kind of "stopper" so min. is 1 and max. is 55?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple if

```
if(i<55){
```

and

```
if(i>1){
```

like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content span").html(i)/55;
  var i = 1;
  $("#n_next").click(function(){
    if(i<5){
     i++;
     $("#content span").html(i)/55;
     var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/'+i+'/before.jpg';
     var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/"+i+"/after.jpg";
     $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
     $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
     console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    }
  });

  $("#n_prev").click(function(){
   if(i>1){
    i--;
    $("#content span").html(i)/55;
    var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/'+i+'/before.jpg';
    var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/"+i+"/after.jpg";
    $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
    $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
    console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var MAX = 55;
    $("#content span").html(i) / MAX;
    var i = 1;
    $("#n_next").click(function () {
        if (i > MAX)
            return;
        i++;
        $("#content span").html(i) / MAX;
        var srcbefore = 'img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/' + i + '/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter = "img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/" + i + "/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src", srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src", srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore + "::" + srcAfter);
    });

    $("#n_prev").click(function () {
        if (i < 1)
            return;
        i--;
        $("#content span").html(i) / MAX;
        var srcbefore = 'img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/' + i + '/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter = "img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/" + i + "/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src", srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src", srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore + "::" + srcAfter);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an if statement that checks when i < 1 or > than 55, and reset it to 55 or 1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content span").html(i)/55;
    var i = 1;
    $("#n_next").click(function(){
        if(i == 55){ i =0 }
        i++;
        $("#content span").html(i)/55;
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    });

     $("#n_prev").click(function(){
        if(i == 1){ i = 56 }
        i--;
        $("#content span").html(i)/55;
        var srcbefore='img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
    });
});

<div><img id="changer1" alt="before" src="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/1/before.jpg" width="540" height="360" /> <img id="changer2" alt="after" src="img/zeitvergleich/Belgien/1/after.jpg" width="540" height="360" />
<div style="float:right" id="content"><span>1</span>/55</div>

<img src="img/prev.png" id="n_prev"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/trnn.png"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/next.png" id="n_next"/>
```